# String array as property of ActiveX in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, activex

I would like to develop an ActiveX Object which will read/write from file to strings. 500 lines/500 strings are enough for me. However I need to expose that strings as properties of the control.

I have tried to use any array as a property but I failed.

My question is can I create a string array as property?

Comment: Why do you want use ActiveX?

Comment: I am using a software to design displays and running them on Windows CE environment. I have common objects like buttons etc. but only way to add custom objects is by designing ActiveX objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VT_SAFEARRAY as parameter in your DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT method and as a return value in your DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET method.

Comment: This is what you mean right:

DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CMyCtrl, "Data_Array", dispidData_Array, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET , VT_SAFEARRAY)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was focused on invokes, not the actual methods. Did the above put you on track? If not, maybe put some more code snippets in your question, so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008, to create a property I right click to lib object of the ActiveX control I am developing in class view. If I write VT_SAFEARRAY for example VS 2008 prompts me and tells me that VT_SAFEARRAY is not variant compatible.

Comment: Then the add member function wizard obviously isn't designed to add members with types other than the C++ standard types. Try adding the member function manually. What counts ist what the compiler thinks about it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried VT_ARRAY (though I wouldn't recommend using it)?